# How to implement SET and TRAP in agent side with pysnmp?

Tags: snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I have implemented a SNMP Agent using pysnmp based on [this](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-scalar-mib-objects) example. This example demonstrates SNMP GET and GETNEXT queries. But I have found no pointer how can I implement SNMP SET and TRAP on top of this code. [Examples](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/twisted/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html) I have found for SET and TRAP are completely different implementation. How can I implement SNMP SET and TRAP on top of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to combine SNMP CommandResponder (which you have already implemented) with SNMP NotificationReceiver, look at [this example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v1arch/asyncore/manager/ntfrcv/transport-tweaks.html#listen-for-notifications-at-ipv4-ipv6-interfaces). You basically can join both examples within the same Python module around a single I/O loop (e.g. `transport dispatcher`).

However, typically, NotificationReceiver resides at the NMS while CommandResponder is SNMP agent running inside the managed software/device.

Supporting SNMP SET within your existing code would require refactoring the way how your MIB objects are stored. With current example they are kept in a non-writeable storage (tuple) and the MIB objects are not designed to change their stored value (they return a constant). So you need to change that one way or the other.

Otherwise supporting SNMP SET is simple - just add condition like this:

```
...
elif reqPDU.isSameTypeWith(pMod.SetRequestPDU()):
    for oid, val in pMod.apiPDU.getVarBinds(reqPDU):
        if oid in mibInstrIdx:
            # put your MIB instrumentation update code here
            # smith like this, but not exactly:
            mibInstrIdx[oid] = mibInstrIdx[oid].clone(val)
            varBinds.append((oid, mibInstrIdx[oid](msgVer)))
        else:
            # No such instance
            varBinds.append((oid, val))
            pendingErrors.append(
                (pMod.apiPDU.setNoSuchInstanceError, errorIndex)
            )
            break
```

into your `cbFun`.

Comment: I have found the solution for SNMP SET earlier. Didn't find any API reference for pysnmp.proto.api module. Then I look up the source on github. From there found some idea.

Actually I am trying to implement trap sender not receiver which will send trap messages to SNMP manager. Found an [example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/ntforg/transport-tweaks.html#trap-over-multiple-transports) of this too.

Comment: I have followed the trap notifier [example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/ntforg/transport-tweaks.html#trap-over-multiple-transports). The trap notifier example there is for SNMP V1. Can't understand how can I implement a trap notifier in SNMP V2C which will send a trap message with an OID and a octet string in V2C?

Comment: @AshfaqurRahman Let's resolve the TRAP sender issue within a separate SO question? To benefit other people that may look that up laster on.